# Fixing CSS float

Tags: html, css

So I created an ID named `top-section`, class named `container` and 2 other classes `logo` & `log-in`. I wanted the background-color of `top-section` to span over 100% of body width and inside `top-section` I have 3 divs with classes logo and log-in. `logo` div needs to float left and `log-in` div to the right. Both these divs are inside `container` div whose width is 80%.Here is my HTML

```
<div id="top-section">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="logo">
            Logo
        </div>
        <div class="log-in">
            Sign In
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

CSS here

```
#top-section{
    background-color: #f5f5f5;
    width: 100%;
    display: inline-block;
    margin: 0 auto;
    overflow: auto;
}
.container{
    width: 80%;
}
#top-section .logo{
    float: left;
}
#top-section .log-in{
    float: right;
}
```

What I want to achieve is the text `Logo` and `Sign In` should've a background-color of `top-section` but at the same time they should not be placed at the extreme end points of body width i.e. inherit a width of 80% from class container so they leave some space from extreme end of body. The class `log-in` is working fine and leaving some space from right but there is some problem  with class `logo` and it is not leaving any space from left. Is it due to float? How do I fix it? Here is my fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/adityasingh773/76wmomh1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to center align your .container class inside of the top-section, so that it isn't left aligned.

```
.container{
    width: 80%;
    margin: 0 auto; /*Add this*/
}
```

Updated fiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/76wmomh1/2/)

Answer (score 1):

just add `margin-left` and `margin-right` to your logo and sign-in respectively.

Try this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76wmomh1/1/)

UPDATE:

Another way is to add `margin: 0 auto` to your `.container`

Comment: Is there a way to achieve it without using margin? I've done this. It has it's own cons.

Comment: you have to mention what are your constraints in the OP

Answer (score 0):

Add `margin: 0 auto;` to `.container`.  It's `80%` the width of `.top-section`, but still sitting on the left.  This will center it and get your other elements where you want them.